# VB notepad spliter

Tags: vb.net, bots, notepad

So I just started a new program and in this program I need a feature that will basically take a text file or just a richtextbox, and then equally split it. So lets say I have a file with 200 lines of text. Then I want to split it up into 10 files of 20 lines. Please help I need some type of direction! -thanks

Comment: So which part are you having trouble with? Reading files, division, …? Have you looked at textboxes’ `Lines` property?

Comment: I need to know what command I can use to make it equally divide the lines of text into different files.

Comment: This may come as a bit of a surprise, but the .NET framework doesn’t come with one, so break down the problem into parts.

Comment: So what about this. Is there a way for it to go lets say every 10 lines and hit enter or just make a blank line?

Comment: Hit Enter? Your question is tagged [tag:bots]; do you want to do this with another program?

Answer (score 0):

Count the textbox length by (textbox1.text.length)i.e.=200 character and divide it by 2 = 100 then make a loop which goes to 200 then keep condition in loop body if it equal to 100 put it to string variable and write it to file and so on and so forth...

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a string array

```
Dim S() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbNewLine)
```

this will allow you to put every line in an item of the array named S
to get the lines count use

```
S.Length
```

OR

```
S.Count()
```

now you got the lines and the lines' count all you have to do to divide them and go from there...